# Deserialize RabbitMQ message generated by C# in Java

Tags: java, c#, serialization, memorystream, binaryformatter

I have a RabbitMQ data service in C# and "fout" some messages. The subscripber/client is in Java. I can receive message, I know how to deserialize in C#, but I do not know how to deserialize the message to object. in Java.

C# Serialize:

```
byte[] message;
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    bf.Serialize(ms, updateMessage);
    message = ms.ToArray();
}
```

C# Deserialize:

```
MyObject message = null;
using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    var binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
    memStream.Write(body, 0, body.Length);
    memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    message = (MyObject)binForm.Deserialize(memStream);
}
```

Java Receiver:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = queueName)
public void receive(??? message ) {
    // deserailize message right here
    // btw, I do not know what type of received message should be initialized.
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you are serialising in the first place. Doesn't RabbitMQ handle all that for you?

Comment: I don't think `BinaryFormatter` is really intended to be used outside of the .NET universe.

Comment: The default RabbitMQ encode is `var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);`, but I use different way to encode message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deserializing an object in Java that was serialized with .NET's build in binary serializer is not possible without great difficulty (you would have to implement the deserializer yourself).

The easiest option would be to use a text-based serialization option such as JSON and XML. There are plenty of tutorials on how to-do this in both C# and Java.

If you need to use a binary format some options to look into would be Google's protocol buffers or apache thrift.

Comment: I can not change publish side (serializer), so the only thing I could do is trying to deserialize the binary array of memory stream to Object. Do you have any idea how to do that? I mean how to implement the serializer myself. Thanks.

Comment: I did not find a way to deserialize .NET's build in the binary serializer. I changed the format of the message from binary of memoryStream to string. And it is easy to handle the binary array of UTF-8 in Java. Thanks for your answer.